# Getting multiprocessing Errors

Tags: python, module

So I have this;

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def run():
    4/0
    sys.exit()

def go(self):
    p = Process(target=run, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

How can get the errors from the Process and maybe store them in a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the function in try/except, blanket catch the exceptions. Use the python logging module to log the stacktrace, and perhaps locals() as well for context.

You could also skip the logging module and just use 'print' to print the exception handling messages to the console.

Answer (score 1):

you can use log module: `import logging` and let each process log the errors/log directly in the log file.

`logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application')`
`logger.warning("Something bad happened")`

Do the following in your code. Note - This is a rotating logger you can use others too.[http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html]

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler 

r_logger = logging.getLogger('parsexmlfiles')

def set_logger()
    FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
    parser_logger = logging.getLogger('A_A_logfile')

    if isdaemon is True:
        # Log into a Log File.
        rotatingFH = RotatingFileHandler("/tmp/A_Alogfile.log", mode='a', 
                                     maxBytes=7340032, backupCount=4,
                                     encoding=None, delay=False)
        rotatingFH.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
                                fmt="%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s", 
                                datefmt=None))
        parser_logger.addHandler(rotatingFH)
        parser_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def run():
    4/0
    r_logger.info("Info Message")
    sys.exit()

def go(self):
    set_logger()
    p = Process(target=run, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Hmm, how could I implement this into the example above?

Comment: @AA - edited the comment. you can use to try, catch in run method, to capture any error while executing the python code.

Comment: Hmm actually, I do not have access to the run() function, I cannot edit it

Comment: do you have the permission to change the main method or from wherever the run() function is called ?

Comment: Yes I do. I do have this permission.

Comment: then call `set_logger()` from there.

Comment: sorry about that, I **misread**. if you don't have permission to change `run()`, then I'm not sure how you can log something from the process.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19609/discussion-between-harman-and-a-a)